# Geometrically Construct a Plane to Create Cross Section or Finding the Cross Section with Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d

I wanted to ask this question so badly because i dont find any answer on google for it.

1. How do we construct cross section that's formed inside a 3d figures (especially cube) (or maybe i should say how do we geometrically construct a plane inside 3d figure that's defined by 3 points)
2. What are the geometrical reasoning, and what is allowed to do and not allowed in order to construct a cross section ?

3.Lastly can we somehow know the shape of cross section with linear algebra (like finding the intersection point, but without plugging in x/y/z value one by one in plane equation) ? .

Actually i have seen 2 question in this site that also ask this, but they didn't explain the geometrical reasoning of why those action are legal to do so i'm a bit confused. Please dont introduce some high level college math because im not even in college yet.

Take this example : construct a plane that goes through point P,Q,R and determine its cross section with the cube !

[Cube with side 6 unit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nww5n.png)

Comment: One needs to be more specific about how the 3D figure is defined.  Many "computational geometry" problems deal with the solid 3D convex polyhedra formed by taking convex combinations of a set of vertices.  In that case a cross-section would be a convex polygon and "finding" it would amount to locating vertices of the polygon.

Comment: For now im just dealing with simple 3D figure like cube, tetrahedron, cuboid

Comment: Defining a plane from 3 points (not all in a common line) is easy, but finding the intersection of a plane with a general solid figure is not so easy.  But the special case of intersections with a cube can be worked out.  A variety of intersections are possible, up to a hexagonal cross-section (and going down to a triangle, or even a line segment or single point).

Comment: Im sure there wouldn't be any convex polygon cross section yet in what im facing , so is there any computation technique in finding the intersection point ?

Comment: For the sake of completeness I should mention that the plane might miss the solid entirely, giving an empty intersection.  Detecting whether there is a nonempty intersection is sometimes posed as a "collision" problem when motion of the solid is considered.  One way to formulate (and solve) the issue of a nonempty intersection would be to pose it in terms of feasibility of a "linear program".

Comment: Well i dont really need to know whether the plane doesnt intersect or not (in fact it's not that complex yet and im sure the problem in my school giving me a problem where the plane intersect all the time)

Comment: If you want "any computation technique in finding the intersection point", then I'd say you do want "to know whether the plane doesn't intersect or not".  Perhaps you have some clarifications to edit in your Question about the purpose of the computation.  Such context often helps Readers to answer in ways that are better suited to your interest and level of study.

Comment: Maybe plugging value is the only way......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is that we can construct an intersection of lines if they lie on the same plane.

1. We start by constructing projections $R'$ and $P'$ of $R$ and $P$ on a plane $ABCD$. We can do it by drawing line parallel to $AE$ (which is perpendicular to $ABCD$ because it's cube) through points $R$ and $P$ and then finding intersections with lines $AD$ and $BC$. The reasoning is the following. Plane $ADHE||ABCD$ and $R\in ADHE$, so $RR'$ should lie on $ADHE$. Since $R'\in ABCD$ and $R'\in ADHE$, then it lies on intersection of those planes, line $AD$. The same applies to $PP'$.

[image]

2. Since $RR'$ and $PP'$ are parallel, we can construct a plane $RR'PP'$. It should obviously contain lines $RP$ and $R'P'$. The intersection of those lines, point $S$, lies on plane $ABCD$ and also lies on section plane $PQR$.

[image]

3. Line $QS$ lies both in plane $PQR$ and in plane $ABCD$, so it is the intersection of those planes. Intersection of $QS$ with lines $BC$ and $AD$ give points $T$ and $U$.

[image]

4. Since $PT$ lies on $BCGF$, it can be intersected with $BF$ and $GC$. The same true for $UR$ and $HD$. We got all the needed intersections of $PQR$ with edges of cube.

[image]

5. Finally, we connect dots.

[image]

Finding the numerical values of intersection is just a thorough study of proportions. For example, $SP':SR'=PP':RR'=6:3=1:2$. Since $DR'=CP'=3$, then $DC$ and $R'P'$ intersect in middle points and $\angle P'R'D=45^\circ$. And so on.

Comment: Thanks for answering, what's not allowed to do in the construction ? and can we somehow find all the intersection with calculation efficiently without plugging x,y,z value one by one to the plane equation of PQR ?

Comment: I added a paragraph on finding intersections.

Comment: what projection is not allowed in this case ? does the projection have to lie on 2 plane or it can be more ?

Comment: I can't understand your question. You can construct everything you want, as long as it makes sense. In terms of lines intersection, not any two lines that are intersecting on the drawing are really intersecting in 3D.

Comment: I mean like can we project one of those point say to the side face or front face instead of the bottom face ?

Comment: Yes, we can do whatever we want, as long as it makes sense